# プリンターのdpiの意味がわかりません

Tags: dpi

- [A4の紙に印刷するのに一番フィットする解像度って何ピクセル×何ピクセルです... - Yahoo!知恵袋](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q129565177)

> 商業印刷（DTPデータ入稿）に使うなら、175線で製版する場合は350dpi必要となりますので、
>   (略）
>   インクジェットプリンタでプリントする程度なら、200dpiで計算し直してください。

ここでいう350dpiや200dpiというのは、プリンター自体の設定のdpiでしょうか？

- [印刷の設定を変更する](http://support.brother.co.jp/j/s/support/html/mfc6490cn_5890cn_jp/doc/html/body/sug-08-5.html)

には下記の通りWxYという表記なので、どうやってプリンターのdpiを考えたらよいのかわかりません。(そもそも自分のプリンターが200dpiなのかどうか確認したい）

```
| 設定             | 解像度                             |
|------------------|-----------------------------------|
| 最高速           | 600×150（カラー）450×300（モノクロ）|
| 高速             | 600×300                           |
| 普通             | 600×600                           |
| きれい           | 1200×1200                         |
| 写真             | 1200×2400                         |
| 写真（最高画質）  | 1200×6000                         |
```

Comment: 解決したい問題がよくわからないのですが、これはdpiが決まらないと上手く行かないことがあるのでしょうか？例えばA4サイズの紙で印刷するので縦横のサイズ上限を制限したいということであれば、絶対単位のptを使うという手段も取れます。仮にhtmlを使っているのであれば、メディアクエリで`@media print` と対象メディアを指定したCSSを書き、そこで縦横のサイズをptを使って指定すれば上手くいくと思います（htmlのタグの組み方で必ずしも上手く行くとは限らないですが…)実装を何でするのかでも具体的にどうしたらいいのかは変わってきますけれども。

Comment: おっしゃる通り、最終的には問題はCSSの単位をmmで指定することによって解きました。この結論にたどり着くまで随分遠回りがあって、その過程でdpiについてよくわからずそもそもプリンターのdpiがいくつなのか気になった次第であります。

Comment: 印刷の品質を担保するためには、元データがある程度の精細度を持つ必要があります。350DPIや200DPIというのは元データの最低限の精細度です。これ以下だとプリンタが高精細でもジャギが目立ちます。CSSで指定したmmは実際にレンダリングする時のDPIとは独立した設定です。出力先が画面ならときは72DPIから108DPI程度、プリンターに対してはテーブルにあるように、600DPIとか1200DPIとか高い精細度でレンダリングして印刷しています。

Comment: リンク先でよく説明されていると思います。「350dpiや200dpiというのは、プリンター自体の設定のdpiでしょうか？」この場合はプリンタのことではなくて画像‌​の画素数がどれくらい必要なのか（Ｎインチ×Ｍインチの広さに何画素の大きさの画像が必要かは画素密度(dpi)から計算できる、リンク先の説明もそのことを言ってます）を意味しています。１ドットが１画素という意味です。

Comment: 印刷屋への原稿は通常ラスターデータかベクターデータです。ラスターならそれがいくつのDPIでレンダリングされたのかを伝えないと正しい大きさに印刷できません（印刷屋さんは印刷結果のサイズで指定されるのを嫌がる傾向にあります。拡大縮小すると品質が保証出来ないからでしょう）。写真の場合ラスターしか選択肢がないので、自前で計算しておく必要があります。リンク先のようにA4で350DPIを担保するなら2893×4092画素の画像が必要ですね。

Comment: レイアウトを決めるときに、品質から大きさを決定するというフローにはならないでしょう。A4の紙のどの位置にどれだけのサイズの写真を載せるかを決めて、その上で300DPIを満たす画素数の写真を用意すればいいわけです。業務用のプリンターが9600DPIだったとして、それを知ってもあまり役に立たないと思います。

Comment: 皆様ありがとうございます。 mm(絶対値)をCSSで設定すれば、dpiにかかわらず内部で計算して出力先に合わせた形にしてくれることは認識しました。 そもそも元データ(画像）が350dpiなどと表現されることが理解できていません。画像は単なるピクセルの集合というデータなので、インチが単位に入っていることが理解できません。インチの‌​概念は画面や印刷してきて初めて出てくるものなので、なぜ画像データの時点で考えることができるのでしょうか？
<br />
`> リンク先のようにA4で350DPIを担保するなら2893×4092画素の画像が必要ですね。` ということから、 やはりプリンタのDPIをまず調べてその数値から画像の大きさを決める必要があると思っています。

Comment: 私の中で混乱の原因になっているのが、モニターは高画質になるほど出力したとき画像が見た目的に小さく表示されるというのがあるのですが、プリンターの場合は高DPIだっとしても問題なくねらった大きさで出力されるということでしょうか。

Comment: 皆様助かりました。頭のなかでずいぶん整理ができました。

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### 350dpi, 200dpi

知恵袋に書かれている 350dpi や　200dpi というのは、画像データの細かさの話です。要するに、

- これより低い解像度・画素数だと、人間が見て粗く感じる・ぼやけて見える
- これより高い解像度・画素数にしても、プリンタの性能上再現できない、もしくは人間には見分けがつかない

といった基準で得られた数字です。例えば「350dpiでA4サイズの印刷をするには2894x4093px必要だ」といったかたちで使われます。

もっとも、画像データのdpiというのは「表示・印刷する際の大きさ(mm)」を計算するための参考値に過ぎません。**画面に表示する際はデータ上の1px＝ディスプレイの1pxとして表示してしまうことが多い**ですし、印刷する際もアプリケーションによっては無視してしまうことがあります。

しかし対応しているソフトの場合、1377x1377pxの画像に350dpiと指定されていれば、これは10cmで出力すべきなんだと解釈し、（どんな印刷解像度のプリンタであれ）10cmになるように処理します。

Windows Vista 以降、[高dpiに対応していないアプリケーションを自動的に拡大表示する機能](http://ascii.jp/elem/000/000/901/901046/)がついていますが、これも96dpi指定の表示を出力解像度に合わせているわけですね。

### 印刷解像度

ところで、一般的にフルカラー画像というのは1pxあたり色の濃さが256階調あるわけですが、印刷する際に吹き付けるインクの濃さを細かく変えるのは困難です。そこで、**原稿の解像度よりもさらに細かく位置を制御する**ことで、1pxあたりの点の大きさ、もとい塗る面積を制御し、濃淡を再現しているのです。この細かさがプリンタの印刷解像度と言われるものです。

ですから、プリンタの解像度が1200dpiだからといって画像データを1200dpiで作成する必要はなく、結局200～350dpi程度のデータで十分、ということになります。

EPSONのサイトにこんな説明もありました。

> - 印刷解像度の整数分の一倍（例えばプリンタの1440dpiの6分の1である240dpiなど）を指定すると、ジャギー（線のギザギザ）が目立たなくなります。
> - モノクロ印刷を行う場合は、印刷解像度と同じ解像度の画像データをご用意ください。
>     <sub>--- http://www.epson.jp/manual/v/vz_3.htm#S-01700-00700-00100 より引用</sub>

同じくEPSONの別のQ&Aでは推奨される解像度についても言及がありました。参考までに。

[[FAQ番号:001875-1]解像度について｜よくある質問(FAQ)｜エプソン](http://faq.epson.jp/faq/00/app/servlet/relatedqa?QID=001875-1#4.)

<sub>※実質的な解像度がそこで頭打ちになるというだけで、ドライバにその解像度で送られる、とは限りません。ちょうどBrotherのプリンタがあったので試してみたところ、.NETの [`PageSettings.PrinterResolution`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.drawing.printing.pagesettings.printerresolution(v=vs.110).aspx) プロパティで調べた解像度は「高速」画質の時だけ300dpi、それ以外はカラーモノクロに関わらず600dpiという結果になりました。</sub>

### 参考

- [プリンターと画像データの“dpi”は違う？ - 日経トレンディネット](http://trendy.nikkeibp.co.jp/article/tec/camera/20040304/107470/)
- [プリンターの解像度](http://homepage2.nifty.com/ttoyoshima/Digicam/PrinterRes.htm)
- [カラープリンタの“解像度”とは？](http://userweb.alles.or.jp/sfujita/jpn/cprn-dpi.htm)
- [DTPの基礎知識-3](http://www.algo.jp/doc/old/old-site/dtp/Graphic/DTP_03.html)　（主にオフセット印刷の話）

Comment: 非常に明確な回答で、新たな発見がありました。階調を含めデバイスの能力に合わせたレンダリングが必要な訳ですね。家庭用のプリンタの場合CMYK系への変換、色空間の補正はプリンタドライバ側の分担でしょうか？プロの場合、紙媒体のデザイナはCMYKで入稿するとも聞いたことがあります。